# SQL Select if within time frame to display certain hours certain columns

Tags: sql

Running a grid view on a asp.net application and i want it to only show between certain hours certain columns,

```
 `IF ((datepart(hh, getdate())) between 5 and 18 
  SELECT 
  ,[Hour5],[Hour6],[Hour7],[Hour8],[Hour9],[Hour10],[Hour11],[Hour12],
   [Hour13],[Hour14],[Hour15],[Hour16],[Hour17],[Hour18]

  FROM [DB]    

   IF ((datepart(hh, getdate())) between 18 and 5
    SELECT 
      ,[Hour18],[Hour19],[Hour20],[Hour21],[Hour22],[Hour23],[Hour0],
 [Hour1],[Hour2],[Hour3],[Hour4],[Hour5]
 FROM [DB]     `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `datepart(hh, getdate()) between 18 and 5` will always be false because it's equivalent to `datepart(hh, getdate()) >= 18 and datepart(hh, getdate()) <= 5`. You might try rewriting it as `datepart(hh, getdate()) <= 5 or datepart(hh, getdate()) >= 18`—note the `or` in place of the `and` in the previous example.

However, I suspect you have another logic error in here too. Right now, if `getdate()` is between 05:00:00 and 05:59:59, or if `getdate()` is between 18:00:00 and 18:59:59, *both* of your predicates will be satisfied. Is that what you intended? If not, you might consider structuring your query in this way:

```
if datepart(hh, getdate()) between 5 and 18
    select /*stuff*/;
else
    select /*other stuff*/;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can work on the logical errors but if the syntax is wrong i cant  :)